# Getting 400 Error when Product Search Magento 2.3.5

Tags: magento2, grid, catalogsearch, magento2.3.5, product-grid

When I tried to search a product in Admin Product Grid iam getting the Error, The corresponding error comes when particular search keyword enters.

> Something went wrong with processing the default view and we have
> restored the filter to its original state.

When dig the issue found a error for the action in network call,
[image]

The Response from the call

```
error: "The product that was requested doesn&#039;t exist. Verify the product and try again."
errorcode: "0"
```

[image]

If there is no product then it leads to show no product only, why it is showing the Error?

Thank You

Answer (score 0):

That error message is used in several places throughout the core code so it's hard to pin down. The most likely place is in the product repository (`vendor/magento/module-catalog/Model/ProductRepository.php`) and you can try temporarily modifying the error thrown to include more useful information, such as the product ID or SKU.

In the past I've tracked similar problems down to individual product records. In one case it was a single value which had a trailing space so sometimes the database would equate it with another value, and sometimes not. In another the problem turned out to be the product's image, in that case I simply opened the file in a photo editor and saved it again. This means it must have been some kind of corrupted file and goes to show how unpredictable the cause might be.

Happy hunting!